# Linux C: segfault error 4 in libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, libmysql

I'm trying to implement a multithreaded tcp server with the following code.

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , client_sock , c , *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");

        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = malloc(1);
        *new_sock = client_sock;

        if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        //pthread_join( sniffer_thread , NULL);
        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
 * This will handle connection for each client
 * */
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int newsockfd = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *message , buffer[2000];
    int n;
    struct auth details;
    char* reply;

    char cmd[100] = {0};    
    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(newsockfd , buffer , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        printf("Incoming data: %s", buffer);

        if(parseData(cmd, buffer, "/", "-"))      /* If received data is compliant */
        {   
            details = authenticate(cmd);
            if (details.verified)                   // If said user can execute this command. 
            {
                reply = execute(cmd);                // Execute.
                n = write(newsockfd, reply, strlen(reply));
                if (n < 0) { error("ERROR writing to socket"); }

                free(reply);
                reply = NULL;

            }
            else                                        // Authentication failed.
            {
                n = write(newsockfd, details.error_msg, strlen(details.error_msg));
                if (n < 0) { error("ERROR writing to socket"); }
                else{
                    if(debug) printf("sent: %s\n", details.error_msg);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    //Free the socket pointer
    free(socket_desc);

    return 0;
}
```

The authenticate function is defined in an implementation file:

```
struct auth authenticate(const char* const command)
{
    struct auth data;
    char* db_pwd;
    char* perm;
    char* username = "testUser";
    char query[200] = {0};

    data.verified = FALSE;
    data.error_msg = "";

    printf("in auth\n");
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    snprintf(query, 200, "SELECT password FROM userlist WHERE user='%s'", username);
    if ((row = mysql_fetch_row(run_query(query))))      // if user is on list
    {
        db_pwd = row[0];

        if(!strcmp(db_pwd, password))
        {
            if (!(strcmp(command, "test")))
            {
                 data.verified = TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

I have a working single threaded version of this program(main) with the same implementation file, the segmentation fault occurs only with the multithreaded version.

- Am I doing something wrong in my code?
- How should I proceed with debugging?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read documentation of [MySQL C API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api.html), notably [§ 23.8.12 C API Threaded Function Descriptions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-thread-functions.html) It internally uses a socket connection to the `mysqld` server process, so you have to serialize all MySQL functions.

So, define your global mutex, and protect all the functions doing mysql calls with that mutex (from a request to fetching all the rows of the reply). Better yet, design your application so that only one single thread (usually the main one) is using mysql functions.

Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`) and perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

If unfamiliar with [mutexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion), you might want to read a [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.
Would you please suggest whether forking a new process(twice to avoid calling wait()) for every new accept() instead of a multithreaded approach would be better? That way I can avoid the mutexes right?

Comment: I did not say anything like that. You can have a multithreaded approach, but you should serialize (with a mutex) all use of MySQL functions. Don't be scared of mutexes (they are essential in multithreaded applications)